# instantiate enum using CString

Tags: c++, string, enums

I have an enum ScaleFactorDatumState:

```
enum ScaleFactorDatumState
{
    Unknown,
    Saturated,
    Unnormalised,
    Locked,
    Warning
};
```

And a CString stateFromFile which will (should) be one of these states, e.g. _T("Unknown").

Is there a concise way to do something like this:

```
ScaleFactorDatumState newState = ScaleFactorDatumState(stateFromFile);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (stateFromFile == _T("Unknown"))
  return Unknown;
...
```

Comment: @technorabble You are writing a parser code, to transform an string to an internal representation. All parsers that transform an string are boring, repetitive and prone to errors. We don't have reflection in C++. If you want a "more beautiful" solution you can create a table to translate your String to an enum, but again you need to mantain your table manually. As an alternative you can take a C++ parser and write a simple enum factory, but you should first read this: http://xkcd.com/974/